# get root path of linux hosting

Tags: php, reference

im trying to get the main path to use it in my code insted of using this way

```
include "../../../lib/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php";
```

and call it like this way

```
include $root_path . "lib/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php";
```

and im using this way to get `$root_path`

```
$username = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];

echo $root_path = "/home/" . $username ."/public_html/"; // root path
```

so is that way good? or wrong or bad?

> im using linux hosting with php 8.1v

Comment: It depends. Having a absolute path is what I would prefer. Maybe your provider delivers an ENV variable you could use instead.

Comment: @MarkusZeller i can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; insted of that?

Comment: Sure. The `$_SERVER` superglobal is perfect for that. But you should check it before using, because if the config changes your application will break.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

is absolutely the right approach. This will give you

> The document root directory under which the current script is
> executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.